# How do I make code open-source?

Tags: open-source, licensing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to share code as open source?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/54018/how-to-share-code-as-open-source)

I have a bunch of code.

I want to make it open-source.

What, technically, do I need to do? Add a bunch of text on the top of each file? Upload it somewhere? Do a rain dance? All of the above? Does it matter which license it is?